# Is there any way to update My gtalk status message using any RSS feed?

Tags: gmail, chat, status, google-talk

I want to know about any possibilities of updating the Gtalk status message by any means? (may be by subscribing to RSS feed, or by just adding a file which gtalk recognizes)?

Is there any gtalk API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gtalk is compatible with [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP), so you can use any XMPP library to set user status.

**UPD**

XMPP is covered by [RFC3920](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920) and [RFC3921](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3921)

Comment: You have linked the Russian (i guess) version of wiki article!! I edited and changed it to english version, but you have edited that again!

Comment: @Vijay Oh, sorry, copy/paste problem =) Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look in to it and i've think of a solution where my visitors can click a link (like twitter share or Facebook like) so that their status message is updated

Comment: Hi 4ndrew, thanks for your answers. That helped me to go in a right path, so i mark yours as accepted answer for this question.